# How to attach a shower drain to iron drain pipe that is offset by 3/4-inch

Tags: plumbing, shower, renovation

One bathroom in my house used to have a tub but at some point, an owner decided to tear that out and just have a giant powder room. I'm putting in a walk-in shower and decided to use a pre-fab shower pan with a 2-inch drain already attached. I found an architect's drawing of the house when the bathtub was in it, and it said the drain was 15-in from the wall. but once I dug up hundreds of pounds of tile and concrete, I found the old 3-inch iron drain pipe is only 14-1/4" away. So I need to bridge a 3/4 of an inch offset, and only have 3-1/2 inch of vertical space to do it. I've included a sketch below. The iron pipe goes at least a foot under the slab foundation of the house, so moving it is not an option. Moving the drain on the shower pan isn't an option either. Any ideas on how to attach the two?

Had the two pipes lined up, I was going to use a Fernco [rubber bushing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001ATFW80). Sigh... [These](https://www.ebay.com/itm/334821991781) exist but are metric so I doubt there will be a good fit. There isn't enough vertical space to use two 22.5-deg angles. Fernco makes longer flexible [pipe couplings](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BZTMNN5) but I worry about narrowing the diameter a lot by mangling it to form a dogleg.

Thanks for any ideas or advice (although comments like "you should have found the drain first" or "send the pan back" aren't all that helpful, right?).

[image]

Comment: [PVC Offset Reducers](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Spears-429-338E-3-x-2-PVC-Schedule-40-Eccentric-Reducer?utm_source=google_ad&utm_medium=pmax&utm_campaign=geo_pmax_test&gclid=Cj0KCQjwn_OlBhDhARIsAG2y6zMsdn8no3elL2UjDnstHTNKibedH3DngBN8OhgjE5HmQmvTgDACQJcaAmr5EALw_wcB) exist. I'm not sure if the length will work for you though, and you'd still have to figure out the connecting from that to your iron pipe...

Comment: Are you limited to 3.5" between pipe ends?

Comment: @Huesmann, unfortunately I am. Bleh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [3" to 2" reducer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00077PW68).  The rubber is probably flexable enough to get things connected.

Comment: Maybe a month too late, but also: https://www.amazon.com/Valterra-T1041-2-Eccentric-Tank-Reducer/dp/B002N5PP46